# Textarea not posting value in form

Tags: php, html, textarea

I've found many solutions regarding similar question but unfortunately none of them solve mine. The form is working fine except the textarea. The form does not post the textarea value, it shows

> > > undefined index: description

this is the html code:

```
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post"> 
 <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Description</label>
                    <textarea name="description" rows="4" cols="50" class="form-control" value=""></textarea>
 </div>
</form>
```

php

```
$description = $_POST['description'];
```

Does anyone know where the problem lies? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try with textarea value="Something" also check where the action of the form is pointing.

Comment: @FatihŞennik i have other input as well actually like text and those works fine and the values stored into db except textarea so I was wondering if it's related to the textarea tag

Comment: I agree with @FatihŞennik and also think you have to remove the value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always ensure you test that the submit `button` has been clicked before accessing the values of your form fields using the `isset` function. This is because as the server load the page the server attempt to retrieve the value of the inputs field which have not yet been entered. as such `undefined`. Another solution is to use another page to handle your form submission.

```
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
     $age = $_POST['age'];
     $description = $_POST['description'];
    }
    ?>
      <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input name="age" />
          <label>Description</label>
          <textarea name="description" rows="4" cols="50" class="form-control" value=""></textarea>
          <button name="submit" value="save">Save</button>
        </div>
      </form>
```